# Best Visual-Studio Like tool for Linux Development

Tags: .net, python, visual-studio, linux, ide

I need to write a few programs for a project I'm currently working on and I'm very much used to Visual Studio 2008 and I do not mind programming in Python but I need to have a comfortable GUI programming ontop of the language itself, and it has to be well integrated and fast. I know that's a lot to ask for but is there any such thing out for Linux?

I know of Mono but I have found it to not be fully compatible or capable of what I want and, to be frank, the programs look like shit running in Linux

edit: I didn't discard GTK#, only Mono Winform

Comment: Mono Winforms support is shockingly bad; one has to wonder why they even bother; Winforms programs are unusable on Mono...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have already discarded [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) the next thing that comes to my mind is: [Netbeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) it has a very nice GUI builder

[alt text http://www.netbeans.org/images/v6/7/screenshots/swing-gui-builder-cut.png](http://www.netbeans.org/images/v6/7/screenshots/swing-gui-builder-cut.png)

The l&f for linux is quite accurate for most apps. Java Swing it in it self a bit harder to grasp than other programming toolkis though.

**EDIT**

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) has:

> ***GTK# Visual Designer***
>
> *Easily build GTK# applications*

[image]
<sub>(source: [monodevelop.com](http://monodevelop.com/@api/deki/files/203/=ss-stetic.png?size=webview))</sub>

I don't think you cant get any closer to VS than that.

Comment: MonoDevelop ain't discarded, it looks to me he discarded Mono's winforms, as that is the only thing what comes to my mind when thinking about looking like shit.

Comment: Yeah, GTK# is fine but Mono WinForms sucks

Answer (score 2):

For python, I've found that [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) has been the best option for [Python development](http://pydev.org/). I've never used it on Linux, though. Only Windows and Mac OS X.

I've also tried [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) with [some success with Python](http://www.netbeans.org/features/python/index.html) but felt that Eclipse was a bit more polished. NetBeans also seems to direct one to Jython which I, personally, didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

Consider me in the text-editor camp for most Linux development (though I gladly and happily use Visual Studio on the Windows side).  That being said, this looks interesting: http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/    And there are a number of other options here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments

Answer (score 1):

If you need a GUI designer, [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) maybe is what you're looking for. It isn't an IDE but saves designs as XML you can easily load by using a GTK+ object in your application. ([GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) is a cross-platform GUI toolkit with C, C++, Python, Mono, etc. bindings)

Answer (score 1):

[KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) used to be very much like Visual Studio, but the last time I looked was some 8 years ago so things may have changed.

Personally I would recommend something cross-platform that you could use both on Windows and Linux (or even Mac). My tool of choice is [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), which has a great Python plugin available: [Pydev](http://pydev.org/). Eclipse has a pretty steep learning curve, but once you are past that it is generally pretty good and there are tons of plugins for all kinds of languages and things you might want. Eclipse does require pretty beefy machine for it to not feel sluggish. It works fine for me on my Dell Latitude [D820](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/linux/ubuntu-8.04-d820.html) and [D830](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/UbuntuHardyHeron64bitOnDellLatitudeD830.html).

Answer (score 1):

[Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) is very much like a Visual Studio for Python.  About a year ago I worked on a team developing in Python, and this was the standard IDE for the team.